# Eclipse code quality check - find ocurrences of comparing Integers using ==?

Tags: eclipse, pmd

Is there a plugin for Eclipse to find occurrences of comparing `Integer`s, `String`s etc. by using `==` and `!=` instead of using the `equals()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) plugin can do that (and it will find a ton of other problems, too).

Comment: Is there an easy way to run code analysis? I'm sorry but I can't find it.